# Get permalink for a post from inside Wordpress and route to a related site

Tags: php, permalinks, redirect, mobile, routing

I built a mobile version of a wordpress site and added some PHP code in the wordpress index.php file to detect mobile users and HTTP-redirects them to [m.website.com](http://m.website.com) (*which is not a wordpress installation. This PHP standalone mobile site scrapes the wp site for posts and displays them*). All works well, and every request to the full site goes to [m.website.com](http://m.website.com) instead.

The only problem is that my team leader wants me to redirect [website.com/2011/04/13/post-title](http://website.com/2011/04/13/post-title) to [m.website.com/2011/04/13/post-title](http://m.website.com/2011/04/13/post-title) for mobile users. And to do this, **my redirection script only needs to know the permalink of the page that index.php is trying to route to**. The mobile site's index.php will handle the permalink once it receives it.

N.B. Currently, if you visit [m.website.com/2011/04/13/post-title](http://m.website.com/2011/04/13/post-title) it displays properly. I only need to know how to trap the permalink from inside wordpress and feed it to my mobile redirection code.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Tom J Nowell's comment below, I am ready to move the redirection script to whatever file it is at which Wordpress figures out the permalink, and not index.php any longer. So that once the permalink is known, a redirection to `m.website.com/router.php?path=2011/04/13/post-title` can be done, which becomes `m.website.com/2011/04/13/post-title` via htaccess. Thanks

Comment: So you want to get the permalink before the file figures out the permalink? ( the process of 'routing' as you call it, is an integral part of figuring out what the current url or permalink is ), as such your question is contradictory

Comment: Thanks. Fair enough, I can move my redirection script to the point at which the routing is done, and then redirect from there. At what point is the permalink figured out, and what file should I inspect, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use responsive design rather than a mobile subdomain copy of the site, however if you really do want this, then put this code in a plugin:

```
// this function doesn't exist prior to wordpress v3.4
if(!function_exists('wp_is_mobile')){
   /**
    * Test if the current browser runs on a mobile device (smart phone, tablet, etc.)
    *
    * @return bool true|false
    */
   function wp_is_mobile() {
       static $is_mobile;

       if ( isset($is_mobile) )
           return $is_mobile;

       if ( empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) {
           $is_mobile = false;
       } elseif ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mobile') !== false // many mobile devices (all iPhone, iPad, etc.)
           || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android') !== false
           || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'BlackBerry') !== false
           || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mini') !== false ) {
               $is_mobile = true;
       } else {
           $is_mobile = false;
       }

       return $is_mobile;
   }
}
add_action('init','mobile_redirect_init');
function mobile_redirect_init(){
    if(wp_is_mobile()){
        $url = 'http://m.'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];;
        wp_redirect($url);
    }
}
```

Comment: (No, I am under instructions not to use a responsive design) Thanks! I'll try this. I already have code to detect mobile, just like your wp_is_mobile above. Can I place the add_action and the mobile_redirect_init() inside the theme functions.php file instead of making it a plugin?

Comment: Also can get_permalink work for the current page? Cos get_permalink says *Note that when used outside The Loop on a posts page (index, archive, etc.) without the ID parameter, it will return the URL of the last post in The Loop, not the permalink for the current page. See: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9963*

Comment: Why would anybody want you not to use a responsive design? hmmmm, I've updated my answer

Comment: Corporate bureaucracy. The client did not pay for a responsive design, and wants a standalone mobile site instead. It's quite complicated, thanks to my Team Leader. Sigh. Thanks for the updated code. Can I use this in the index.php page then? Or functions page? Or where? I am not allowed to install plugins (for the same bureaucratic reason).

Comment: I placed it in index.php and I'm getting internal error 500 (only on mobile phones). The server encountered an internal error and could not meet your request.

Comment: the themes functions.php then, but I would think building 2 sites would cost more not less than a responsive design =s

Comment: that's because by that point init has already ran, and the headers have already been sent, place it in functions.php

Comment: Thanks Tom. (Actually the main site already existed. We're only building the mobile one). You gave me so many pointers and took valuable time, so I will accept your answer. But now that I have realized I dont need permalinks anyway, what I did was `$url = 'http://m.'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];` and then I checked if it is mobile, and redirected to that URL if so. Worked fine.

Comment: I've ammended my answer, I'd still advise you use an init hook instead of modifying index.php, as you should never modify wordpress core files